# Qt find all dependencies of a project

Tags: qt, deployment, dependencies, qtwebengine, qt-installer

I am creating a web browser with Qt 5.10.1 and I would like to export it with the Qt Installer Framework. I am looking for a way to know all the dependencies (libs, plugins...) my application has to export them with the binary file. I already used ldd for the libs but I don't know how to do for the plugins.

Thanks for your help.

When I use linuxdeployqt it seems to work but when I run the program I get

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Could not find QtWebEngineProcess
[22299:22299:0328/184840.249157:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(182)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
#0 0x7f2a8ffd60a5 <unknown>
#1 0x7f2a8ffebeca <unknown>
#2 0x7f2a8f62efc3 <unknown>
#3 0x7f2a8f62dc3b <unknown>
#4 0x7f2a8f62e219 <unknown>
#5 0x7f2a8f27193a <unknown>
#6 0x7f2a8f276e76 <unknown>
#7 0x7f2a8ed94600 <unknown>
#8 0x7f2a8ed95b25 <unknown>
#9 0x7f2a8ed84ee9 <unknown>
#10 0x7f2a8ed850be QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::WebContentsAdapter()
#11 0x7f2a973fa441 <unknown>
#12 0x7f2a973faf24 QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage()
#13 0x7f2a97408ebb QWebEngineView::page()
#14 0x7f2a97409179 QWebEngineView::settings()
#15 0x00000040861f WebPage::WebPage()
#16 0x0000004079d6 MainWindow::addTab()
#17 0x0000004075c9 MainWindow::MainWindow()
#18 0x000000408441 Launcher::Launcher()
#19 0x000000406519 main
#20 0x7f2a94cdb830 __libc_start_main
#21 0x000000406419 _start

Received signal 6
#0 0x7f2a8ffd60a5 <unknown>
#1 0x7f2a8ed17141 <unknown>
#2 0x7f2a8ffd643d <unknown>
#3 0x7f2a94cf04b0 <unknown>
#4 0x7f2a94cf0428 gsignal
#5 0x7f2a94cf202a abort
#6 0x7f2a8ffd5dc5 <unknown>
#7 0x7f2a8ffec1ed <unknown>
#8 0x7f2a8f62efc3 <unknown>
#9 0x7f2a8f62dc3b <unknown>
#10 0x7f2a8f62e219 <unknown>
#11 0x7f2a8f27193a <unknown>
#12 0x7f2a8f276e76 <unknown>
#13 0x7f2a8ed94600 <unknown>
#14 0x7f2a8ed95b25 <unknown>
#15 0x7f2a8ed84ee9 <unknown>
#16 0x7f2a8ed850be QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::WebContentsAdapter()
#17 0x7f2a973fa441 <unknown>
#18 0x7f2a973faf24 QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage()
#19 0x7f2a97408ebb QWebEngineView::page()
#20 0x7f2a97409179 QWebEngineView::settings()
#21 0x00000040861f WebPage::WebPage()
#22 0x0000004079d6 MainWindow::addTab()
#23 0x0000004075c9 MainWindow::MainWindow()
#24 0x000000408441 Launcher::Launcher()
#25 0x000000406519 main
#26 0x7f2a94cdb830 __libc_start_main
#27 0x000000406419 _start
  r8: ffff80005d51c978  r9: ffff80005d51c968 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000206
 r12: 00007fffa41a6fe0 r13: 00000000000000ac r14: 00007fffa41a7210 r15: 00007fffa41a7980
  di: 000000000000571b  si: 000000000000571b  bp: 00007f2a9562ad40  bx: 00007fffa41a7760
  dx: 0000000000000006  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f2a94cf0428  sp: 00007fffa41a6e78
  ip: 00007f2a94cf0428 efl: 0000000000000206 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) to find all used libraries and plugins. Qt does not ship anything like windeployqt for linux.

> This Linux Deployment Tool, linuxdeployqt, takes an application as
>   input and makes it self-contained by copying in the resources that the
>   application uses (like libraries, graphics, and plugins) into a
>   bundle. The resulting bundle can be distributed as an AppDir or as an
>   AppImage to users, or can be put into cross-distribution packages.

If you are on Windows, you can use the [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) which comes with Qt.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, look at my edit for the error message

Comment: linuxdeployqt is your best choice. Verify the QtWebEngine part manually. Could be that there is a bug in linuxdeployqt or Qt 5.10.1 is simply too new.